# How to spot and fix un-weighted vertices? blender to unity fbx

Tags: unity, .fbx

I  have read previous solutions still I cant find the glitch

**tried in blender:** Vertex Mode > Header 'Select' menu > 'Select by Trait' > 'Select Ungrouped Verts
**tried in blender:** moving bones to spot lagging vertices...
made sure all vertices are weight painted (nothing has val of 0)

[image: Current scene in blender]

all vertices are weighted I have moved all bones to be sure I weighted all and also normalized weights to find any unweighted (in weight painting mode: Menu:>weights> Normalise)

nothing should be imported as zero yet... imported into unity
i get...

How to fix?

[image]